# Get JSON from URL, return array and count instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to map the `JSON` from the URL to an `array` but I think my mapping of the data isn't correct. I want to find every `value` inside of `attributes` and count how many instances of each `value` there are in the JSON file/ array.

```
[
  {
    name: "1",
    attributes: [
      {
        trait_type: "hat",
        value: "blue"
      },
      {
        trait_type: "hair",
        value: "red"
      }
    ]
  } 
];
```

```js
$.getJSON(
  "https://jsonware.com/api/v1/json/3c53cbcd-5351-4fba-8b89-5f1fb009e857",
  function (data) {
    var items = $.map(data.attributes, function (i) {
      return i.value;
      const result = data.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => ((acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1), acc),
        {}
      );
      console.log(result);
      console.log(items);
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There will me no code run after `return i.value;`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want from the call.

There will me no code run after `return i.value;` so the console.logs will not run

The values you are getting cannot be added.

Here I get an array of all values. jQuery not needed

```js
fetch(
  "https://jsonware.com/api/v1/json/3c53cbcd-5351-4fba-8b89-5f1fb009e857")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { 
    const values = Object.values(data).flatMap(item => ({[item.name]:item.attributes.map(attr => attr.value )}))
    values.forEach(val => console.log(Object.keys(val)[0],Object.values(val)[0].length)) 
    const allValues = Object.values(data).map(item => item.attributes.map(attr => attr.value ))
    console.log("All values: ",allValues.length,allValues)
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Because data is not an array

Comment: I want to count how many times a trait appears in the JSON file total (i.e the "value" data). For instance, in the JSON from the question, Red =1 and Blue =1 since they only appear in the array once. If Red was there 5 times total it would return Red=5